# Macbook Air loses modifier key remapping when hub unplugged

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, keybindings

TLDR: My Macbook Air forgets my remapped modifier keys when I unplug and replug the USB hub my keyboard is on. There have been past questions about forgetting modifier key settings but those were either random or on reboot, not on keyboard removal.

--

I've have a 2021 MacBook Air (MacOS 12.1). I've remapped the modifier keys on both the built-in keyboard and my external keyboard using the Keyboard System Preferences.

For the first week I owned it, I had the external keyboard plugged in to one of the USB ports, and everything worked as expected. (to be exact, I had it plugged in to an old unpowered USB-A hub, which was plugged in to an A-to-C converter, which was plugged in to the computer).

After that, I got an Anker USB hub with pass-through charging so I could charge while having my peripherals plugged in. I've noticed that **when I unplug that hub, and later plug it back in, the modifier keys *sometimes* have reverted to their default settings**. Sometimes the modifier keys on the built-in keyboard revert as well! And sometimes neither one happens.

If I wait for this to happen, and then switch back to the old USB setup (keyboard plugged into old-style USB-A hub), then it remembers my custom modifier key settings again! But if I switch back to the Anker powered hub, it goes back to the defaults.

Question: **Why are my modifier keys resetting to defaults after the hub is unplugged, *or*, how can I get it to stop?**

Notes:

- The keyboard is plugged into the same port on the hub every time.
- I would ideally like a solution that's not "Install Karabiner"
- I've tried running First Aid from Disk Utility and nothing came up
- This is not a duplicate of existing questions because it's not happening on logout or reboot, nor is it happening randomly -- I've pinpointed it to happening when I unplug and replug a particular USB hub. (and the only answers I've seen to those past questions are "install Karabiner")
- Going back to the old hub isn't sustainable because it means I can't have my keyboard, monitor, and power plugged in at the same time.

Comment: I have a similar issue with a Macbook Pro (2020, 13") and Apple keyboard (US A1242) plugged in to a [Plugable USB-C hub](https://plugable.com/products/usbc-7in1).  Unplugging the keyboard causes OSX to forget that I want Caps Lock remapped to Control. Every time.